Fixed column header in datatable ignoring background color
I have a table that shows data in two different units across 12 months for four different channels. I need that the first column, which contains the channel information, stays in place when I scroll to the right, so I can see what information I'm looking at. However, after I fixate the first column, it completely ignores the background-color argument, but not the color, which makes it completely white. I need it to have the same color as the rest of the header.
This is how it looks:

This is how I need it to be:

This is my code:
fix_doubled_months <- function(month){
  
  month_1 <- str_extract(month, "[0-9]{6}")
  
  month_final <- character(length(month))
  
  month_final[str_detect(month, "dollar")] <- month_1[str_detect(month, "dollar")]
  month_final[str_detect(month, "lbs")] <- paste0(" ", month_1[str_detect(month, "lbs")], " ")
  
  return(month_final)
  
}

distribution_summary <- tibble(
  date = rep(seq(from = as.Date("2023-01-01"), length.out = 12, by = "+1 month"), times = 8),
  channels = rep(rep(paste0("Channel ", 1:4), each = 12), 2),
  value = round(rnorm(96, 500, 100), 2),
  unit = rep(c("lbs", "dollars"), each = 48)
) |> 
  mutate(date = format(date, format = "%Y%m"),
         date_unit = paste0(date, "_", unit)) |> 
  select(-c(date, unit)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = date_unit, values_from = value) |> 
  rename_at(vars(matches("^[0-9]{6}_")), fix_doubled_months)

container_summary <- withTags(table(
  class = "display",
  thead(
    tr(
      th(rowspan = 1, ""),
      th(colspan = (length(distribution_summary) - 2)/2, "Lbs"),
      th(colspan = (length(distribution_summary) - 2)/2, "$"),
    ),
    tr(
      lapply(names(distribution_summary), th)
    )
  )
))

distribution_summary |> 
  datatable(
    rownames = FALSE,
    extensions = "FixedColumns",
    container = container_summary,
    options = list(fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 1),
                   scrollX = TRUE,
                   scrollY = FALSE,
                   dom = "t",
                   initComplete = JS(
                     "function(settings, json) {",
                     "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#4F2170', 'color': '#FFFFFF', 'white-space': 'nowrap'});",
                     "}"
                   ))) |>
  formatStyle(names(distribution_summary), "white-space" = "nowrap") |>
  formatStyle("channels", backgroundColor = "#4F2170", color = "#FFFFFF", fontWeight = "bold")


Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.
